# MySQL: How to group table into categories?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with a user column, and a category column.  How can I write a MySQL query so that I find the number of users in each category? (I don't know the name of the categories beforehand).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select category, count(user) from my_table group by category
```

where `my_table` is your table, `category`is your category column, and `user`is your user column

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
select category, count(users) from table
group by category;
```